# How to display comma or thousandSeparator in extjs NumberFiled in modern?

Tags: javascript, extjs, split, sencha-touch

I really to solve this issue ,get many issue  ,I want to create mobile App so ,need to diplay keyboard number :0-9 ,want to allow (,) in Input field

```
{

   xtype: 'numberfield',
   name:'appliedAmount',
   readOnly: false,
   itemId: 'payment1',
   cls : 'txtAlignRight',
   flex : 4,
   value: '0',
   anchor: '100%',
   useThousandSeparator: true,
   thousandSeparator:',',
   maxLength : 15,
   autoComplete: false,
   autoCorrect: false,
   clearIcon: false,
   originalValue: true,
   required: true,
   listeners:{
      focus:function(obj,nf,evt){
         App.security.GlobalFunc.spliteNum(obj);
      },
   },

   spliteNum: function(obj){

            var num = obj.getValue();
            num.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\w{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
            console.info('num',num)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the numberfield like this:

```
    Ext.define('Ext.override.field.Number', {
       override: 'Ext.field.Number',

       initialize: function(){
          this.callParent(arguments);
          this.element.down("input").on('keydown', this.filterChars,    this);
       },

       /**
        * prevent undefined characters for decimals
        */
       filterChars: function(e){
           var keyCode = e.event.keyCode;
           var specialChars = [13,8,46,37,38,39,40,191]; // enter, backspace, delete, up, down, left, right, comma

           if(!((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || (keyCode >= 96 && keyCode <= 105) || (specialChars.indexOf(keyCode) != -1))){
               e.stopEvent();
               return false;
           }
       }
   });
```

This way, the field is going to filter all chars except (0-9,).

Comment: Best thank sir, can I ask u  some If I wan use **extent: 'Ext.field.Number',**   replace ** override: 'Ext.field.Number',** , can possible to use it or not , How about filter char except (0-9,) How can I use or How can I write it in code   , can u help me to solve issue

Comment: You can user 'extend' yes. Then you can use it as a diferent field. If you want to filter different chars you have to add it to the `specialChars` list. (their ascii codes)

Comment: Thank ur aswer , How about Keyboard Display Mobile , Display only number or not , cause in my issue want to display only Keyboard Number  [0-9] and SpecialChar **comma(,)**,

Comment: İt works in mobile too. But you cannot change the display of keyboard that way. There is no device apis for that. You can use input type=number maybe so it will show you the number keyboard

Comment: Best thank for answer  , How about ** Input type = number ** can allow comm  or not ? But I think not allow , can u help me